# Box2D move to destination by accelerating, moving with constant speed and decelerating at the end

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am building a top-down view game, something like Pokemon.

My character needs to move to mouse click position. I would like it to first accelerate to its max speed, keep moving with that speed and then decelerate back to speed 0 once reaching the destination.

I got the deceleration working as follow:

```
Vector2 linearVelocity = body.getLinearVelocity();
boolean applyForce = false;
if(Math.abs(linearVelocity.x) >= Float.MIN_VALUE * 10) {
    linearVelocity.x *= -10;
    applyForce = true;
}
if(Math.abs(linearVelocity.y) >= Float.MIN_VALUE * 10) {
    linearVelocity.y *= -10;
    applyForce = true;
}
if(applyForce) {
    body.applyForce(linearVelocity, body.getWorldCenter(), true);
}
```

But I am struggling with acceleration and moving at a constant speed. I found [this article](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/constant-speed) to be helpful, but my implementation just setting the impulse to 1,1 or 0,0

```
Vector2 linearVelocity = body.getLinearVelocity();
linearVelocity.x = body.getMass() * (maxSpeed - linearVelocity.x);
linearVelocity.y = body.getMass() * (maxSpeed - linearVelocity.y);

body.applyLinearImpulse(linearVelocity, body.getWorldCenter(), true);
```

Also, I have been reading about solutions that change the leaner velocity directly, however, this isn't a solution I would like to use.

To sum it up this is what I need help with:

- How to accelerate to a constant speed?
- How to stop at exactly my destination?